# How to subscribe to get ShareLinkTask notifications in Windows Phone Mango?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

In windows Phone Mango there is [ShareLinkTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.sharelinktask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) that allows users to share URL over email or with some application (Twitter client etc).

I cannot find phone API to subscribe my application to be able to receive URLs like that.

I would like my application to be on the list off apps to which user can share URL when he wants for example with long press on link in Internet Explorer and be able to get URL info when user shares that link with my app.

Comment: You are wanting Windows 8 Contract-like features on the Windows Phone, isn't it :) A lot of us 3rd party devs have felt the need. Request it on Windows Phone User Voice site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are only [Pictures Extensibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202976%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) and [Search Extensibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202969%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) exists for Windows Phone 7

All extensions are declared in WMAppManifest.xml in `extensions` scope, so you can check yourself that there are no more extensions at that moment

Answer (score 1):

If you decompile the Microsoft.Phone assembly and look at the class in question, you can see that this API call is hard coded to invoke the Me application via interop and does not utilize any kind of a registered application lookup. It certainly seems like it would be easy enough for MS to implement however.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at the moment.

Comment: Any proof or article where its stated its not possible? 
Because it seems Seesmic app is on that share link apps list, so why any other custom app cannot be there?

Comment: @Roboblob where is this seen in seesmic? I do not see it using share link in IE.